# wlan0: deauthenticating by local choice

Tags: debian, yocto, systemd, systemctl, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to set up station mode on my device. It works fine if i give the wpa_supplicant command on command line after boot up. But disconnects when i give those commands in a script and then make a systemd service. And after it disconnects, wlan0 still has the ip address. and i have to flush it using `ip addr flush dev wlan0`. (Also, my wpa_supplicant executable is in /home/root.)

**This works:** Below are the commands which i gave manually on cli and i was able to ping. No issues.

```
/home/root/wpa_supplicant -B -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
dhclient -i wlan0
```

Or the script `./station_mode.sh` can be ran instead and it gives no error. I'm getting the error only when i start the `station.service` which is given below.

---

**This doesn't work -** Same commands given in service throws error.

**My script : station_mode.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

rfkill unblock all
/home/root/wpa_supplicant -B -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
dhclient -i wlan0
```

**My systemd service: /etc/systemd/system/station.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=station mode service.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh /home/root/station_mode.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Commands i gave:**

```
systemctl stop wpa_supplicant
systemctl disable --now wpa_supplicant
systemctl start station
```

**Output:**

```
[ 2303.299834] wlan0: authenticate with be:37:a5:d8:96:36
[ 2303.334731] wlan0: send auth to be:37:a5:d8:96:36 (try 1/3)
[ 2303.344189] wlan0: authenticated
[ 2303.348966] wlan0: associate with be:37:a5:d8:96:36 (try 1/3)
[ 2303.369211] wlan0: RX AssocResp from be:37:a5:d8:96:36 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 2303.384351] wlan0: associated
[ 2320.245795] wlan0: deauthenticating from be:37:a5:d8:96:36 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

Answer (score 1):

I did `journalctl -f` and found `State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.` that is dhclient is getting killed. Then i remembered that `wpa_supplicant` goes into background in my  `station_mode.sh` script.

So,`Type` should be `forking` instead of `simple` in `station.service`.